# Create a factor from list

Tags: r

I'm redoing some old university essays to convert it from Stata to R to learn R, and am trying to find a way to take a variable of countries, and create a new variable with a factor of being an OECD member or Non-member.

I have tried to mutate from dplyr with an if-else statement, but it does not seem to work, and all the googling I have tried seem to just show releveling existing factors and such.

As an example (country_name contains names of all the countries in the world, shortended for ease of readability):

```r
df <- data.frame(country_name = c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Algeria", "Bahrain", "Comoros"))

df <- df %>% mutate(OECD = ifelse(country_name = c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium"), "OECD", "Non-OECD")
```

I would have expected that the row containing "Australia", "Austria", "Belgium" would have gotten the factor level of OECD, while "Algeria", "Bahrain", "Comoros" would have gotten Non-OECD.

Ps, as this is my second question ever, any tips on how to improve my question making are much appreciated!

SOLVED: As pointed out in the accepted answer below, I should have used the %in% operator. Many thanks!

Comment: you need `%in%` do `df %>% mutate(OECD = ifelse(country_name %in% c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium"), "OECD", "Non-OECD"))` Or directly `df$OECD <- ifelse(df$country_name %in% c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium"), "OECD", "Non-OECD")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `%in%`.

If you want to remain within the **tidyverse** framework then:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(OECD = ifelse(df[,"country_name"] %in% c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium"), "OECD", "Non-OECD"))
```

Or for a **base R** way:

```
df[,"OECD"] <- ifelse(df[,"country_name"] %in% c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium"), "OECD", "Non-OECD")
```

Or **data.table** way (load data.table package and use `data.table()` instead of `data.frame()`)

```
df[, OECD := "Non-OECD"][country_name %in% c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium"), OECD := "OECD"]
```

This data.table method is making a new variable where all are "Non-OECD" then converting specific ones to "OECD" - I'm just learning data.table myself and really liking it.

Comment: Thank you! And @Ronak Shah who gave the same answer as a comment, this worked perfectly!

Comment: No worries, just added a base R and data.table version too -as a general comment, if you're new to R you should consider using tools from more than just the tidyverse, tidyverse is a toolbox with a lot of (very good) tools, but sometimes there's toolbox with tools more suited to the task.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Just missing the "==" and a ")"

```
df <- df %>% mutate(OECD = ifelse(country_name == c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium"), "OECD", "Non-OECD"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This however had problem with the dataset I worked with, since it contained Australia several times, and only marked every third of them as OECD. Something I now realise I should have mentioned in my question!  =)